# How does PHP determine date format for a strtotime() call

Tags: php, date

Currently  working with a company that sends info via XML which is read and inserted into our database and they've asked how they want us to send dates through, string, integer timestamp etc and it peaked my curiosity a little for me to google but not able to find the answer to the following question.

If a string for a date is sent as `03/01/2016` how does php when convert into a timestamp using `strtotime()` determine the format?

UK its read as 3rd January 2016 but to the US its 1st March 2016 so how does php know to convert it to the correct region?

Does it use timezone set in the php.ini? does something have to be declared beforehand.

Never really though about it and curious to know as it would probably make my dealings a lot easier in future if information such as a date is given to me in that format

Comment: If only this was documented… *cough* http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` returns timestamp and it only parses date in specific format like "m/d/y" or "d-m-y" or "d.m.y". It is clearly state on [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that:

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a
>   time zone is specified in that parameter.

And regarding format accepted:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks yeah i figured YYYY-MM-DD is the preferred choice to avoid confusion i was just curious to see how it dealt with ambiguous date formats, appreciate the answer